# How to make object return generic

Tags: java, json, generics

I am looking at the following Gson library provided by google. In a tutorial I am following I have found the following code snippet;

```
public class JsonToJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try(Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(JsonToJava.class.getResourceAsStream("/Server1.json"), "UTF-8")){
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            Person p = gson.fromJson(reader, Person.class);
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to make this generic, for example, if you have the following parameters

```
public Object getObjectFromJSONString(String jsonString, Class classType){
```

Then we know the class type, is it possible to return any object type or would I have to have individual methods, convertJSONToClassA, convertJSONToClassB, convertJSONToClassC and so on?

Comment: wait there, of course, i just wouldn't need to assign it

Comment: You can use generics to avoid the need the use of Object. This would also mean you'd avoid casts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns whatever the generic type parameter of `classType` is. If you invoke it with `Class<String>`, then it returns a `String`, etc...

```
public <T> T getObjectFromJSONString(String jsonString, Class<T> classType) {
    // Your code here
}
```

This is exactly what the implementation of `Gson#fromJson(String, Class)` does.

Answer (score 1):

I think following is what you want instead

```
public <T> T getObjectFromJSONString(String jsonString, Class<T> classType) {
```

The method still does the same thing but now instead of always returning an instance of `Object`, it returns an instance of whatever class you pass it as argument.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the source file of Gson (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/Gson.java)
Method fromJson is parametrized as you want.

```
public <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> classOfT)
```

Answer (score 0):

### THE EXISTING METHOD:

```
 fromJson(Reader reader, Class classType);
```

This method actually takes whatever object type you need and converts your json to it.

### THE WRAPPER METHOD:

```
public <T> T convertJsonToJava(Reader reader, Class<T> clazz ) {

    T javaObject = null; // Declare the intended object to return

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create(); // Create a Gson instance
    javaObject  = gson.fromJson(reader, clazz); // Get your object from Json

    return javaObject ; // Return your object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the classType parameter for this.

java's generics mechanism can only resolve generic methods by parameter types, not values.

What you **can** do, assuming your Json objects have a default constructor (and most do) is 
to actually instantiate an object param so it can be used as a hint to the generics resolver. Something like this:

```
   Person p = readJson(reader, new Person());
   Car c = readJson(reader, new Car());
   House h = readJson(reader, new ());
```

Where:

```
   public <T> T readJson(Reader reader, Object obj) {
        return  gson.fromJson(reader, obj.getClass());
   }
```